# how can I convert my multiline if statement into a single stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an array of Strings:

```
String[] myArrayString = ...
```

It may contain elements or be null. I wrote the following method:

```
String myName = "";
if(myArrayString != null) {
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String tagID : myArrayString) {
        Tag tag = tagManager.resolve(tagID);
        if (tag != null) {
            temp.add(resolveTagName(tag.getName()));
        }
    }
    myName = temp.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(joining(" "));
    myName = myName.substring(myName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    return myName;
}
```

I have a feeling it is not efficient enough and might be done in one single stream (or possibly two). Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can indeed be converted to use one single stream. The for loop simply transforms each element of the string array (`map`) and filters the `null` ones (`filter`), then performs another transformation (`map`):

```
String myName = "";
if(myArrayString != null) {
    myName = Arrays.stream(myArrayString)
                        .map(tagManager::resolve)
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .map(x -> resolveTagName(x.getName()))
                        .collect(joining(" "));
    myName = myName.substring(myName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    return myName;
}
```

Also note that streams are not necessarily more efficient than a for loop, as it has some overheads as well. To measure performance, you use a profiler, not just by reading the code.

Comment: The `.map(Object::toString)` is obsolete (it was already in the OP’s code where `temp` clearly was declared as `List<String>`, so `resolveTagName` must already return a `String`)

Comment: @Holger Oh yeah. Thanks.